# Progressively add image (arrays)

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays

So I am creating a game where a spaceship moves and it must avoid a fireball image in order to win. My issue is that I have only one fireball looping over and over. Instead, I would like to have many fireballs, which are multiplied as time passes. I think I should need to incorporate an array and use push() method but I tried and it didn't worked. If anyone could help me, it would be very appreciated. Thanks

```
//Fireball script
function fireballScript(offset) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (window.innerWidth - offset))
}
let fireballMovement = {
    x: fireballScript(fireball.offsetWidth),
    y: 0
}
const fireLoop = function () {
    fireballMovement.y += 1
    fireball.style.top = fireballMovement.y + 'px'
    if (fireballMovement.y > window.innerHeight) {
        fireballMovement.x = fireballScript(fireball.offsetWidth)
        fireball.style.left = fireballMovement.x + 'px'
        fireballMovement.y = 0
        fireball.setAttribute('hit', false)
    }
}
fireball.style.left = fireballMovement.x + 'px'
let fireballSpeed = setInterval(fireLoop, 1000 / 250)

let fireball = document.querySelector("#fireball")


<img src = "Photo/fireball.png" id = "fireball" >

//Stop game on collision
function checkCollision() {
    if (detectOverlap(spaceship, fireball) && fireball.getAttribute('hit') == 'false') {
        hits++
        fireball.setAttribute('hit', true)
        alert("lost")
    }
    setTimeout(checkCollision, 1)
}
var detectOverlap = (function () {
    function getPositions(spaceship) {
        var pos = spaceship.getBoundingClientRect()
        return [[pos.left, pos.right], [pos.top, pos.bottom]]
    }

    function comparePositions(p1, p2) {
        let r1 = p1[0] < p2[0] ? p1 : p2
        let r2 = p1[0] < p2[0] ? p2 : p1
        return r1[1] > r2[0] || r1[0] === r2[0]
    }
    return function (a, b) {
        var pos1 = getPositions(a),
            pos2 = getPositions(b)
        return comparePositions(pos1[0], pos2[0]) && comparePositions(pos1[1], pos2[1])
    }
})()

let spaceship = document.querySelector("#icon")
<img src = "Photo/Spaceship1.png" id="icon">
```

*Ps: I asked this question a dozen of times but I could never get an answer which is incorporate into my code. It would be very helpful if someone could fix this... thanks again*

Comment: If something is missing (eg: you say my code is not complete don't hesitate to ask me to post more code). Anyway, I think I posted what is appropriate to answer the question...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to have an array of fireballs

```
var fireballs = [];
```

Make a constructor for fireballs instead of putting them directly in the html

```
function fireball(x, y) {
    movementX = x;
    movementY = y;
}
```

Then push new ones into the array with dynamic position values. To add them to the document, you need to append them to a parent element. If the `<body>` is that parent, you'd do this:

```
let f = new fireball(10, 20)
fireballs.push(f)
document.body.appendChild(f)
```

In your update, iterate through the fireballs and update their movement.

```
fireballs.forEach((fireball) => {
    // update position for each fireball
});
```

Comment: That is very kind Dan Mullin but would it be possible to incorporate this to my code? Thanks a lot. (if you need whole code just ask)

Comment: The code requires some major refactoring to support multiple fireballs unfortunately. I ran into this problem a few times for the first few games I created. The basic idea is to take all of the code that you wrote for moving the one fireball into the `forEach()` function. Your doing the exact same thing to each fireball, so you can almost just copy/paste the code you have into that function. Make a movement function to handle the movement, then just call your functions in sequence. Move, check collision, etc.

Comment: @Thomas - Dan has provided a very good answer here. You need to go off and practice using arrays and arrays of objects. If Dan writes all the code for you then you won't learn anything and you won't have written a game, Dan will have.

Comment: Lee Taylor, you are right that I won't learn much if I only copy and paste but I won't finish the game on time if I do this alone... so my only solution is to copy and paste a good answer in order to complete the game... hope you understand.